# Moving a photo to local data directory in Onsen/Cordova app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, onsen-ui, monaca

I am working on a Onsen/Cordova mobile app, using Monaca for development and an Android phone for testing, that takes pictures to attach to output from the app. I have this code to take a picture and copy it to cordova.file.dataDirectory:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function(imgUri) { // Success callback
        // Get FileEntry object for the new photo
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        imgUri,
        function(fileEntry){
            alert('Success - Before: ' + JSON.stringify(fileEntry));
            newFileName = fileEntry.name;
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory,
                function(dirEntry) {
                    // move the file to a new directory and rename it
                    fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, newFileName, function success() {
                        alert('Copy operation successful - After moving: ' + JSON.stringify(fileEntry) 
                            + '\nURL: ' + fileEntry.toURL());
                        $scope.photos.unshift(fileEntry.toURL());
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }, 
                    function failure(){
                        alert('Failed to move file.');
                    });
                },
                function failure(){
                    alert('Failed to get local FS for data directory.');
                });
        },
        function failure(){
            alert('Failed to get local FS for new image.');
        });
    },
    function() { // Error callback
        // We end up here if the photo selection/shoot is cancelled. So we do nothing.
        return;
    },
    opts // Options 
);
```

What happens, unfortunately, is that although all the success callbacks are triggered, the alerts display the same path for a photo before and after moving it - *file://storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/cache/* - while the path to cordova.file.dataDirectory is *file:///data/user/0/mobi.monaca.debugger.files/* .

What is incorrect in this code?

Answer (score 2):

Did you also tried 'copyTo' instead of 'moveTo'? I've read my old code and I've seen I use copyTo. I remember the moveTo were blocked by the OS (read somewhere googlin it), but sincerely I don't know for which Android versions.
If the 'copyTo' function works for you, this could be the reason.

EDIT: This is my working code. Check and see differences (filesystem maybe?)

```
function manipulate_img_url(fileUri) {
    console.log("fileUri: "+fileUri);
    window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
          fileUri,
          function(fileEntry){
              console.log("Start elaboration: "+JSON.stringify(fileEntry)); // This give me the native url: 'nativeURL':"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.intel.appx.RotarApp.xwalk15/cache/1465151572273.jpg"
                newFileUri  = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "images/";
              console.log("newFileUri: "+newFileUri);
                oldFileUri  = fileUri;
              console.log("oldFileUri: "+oldFileUri);
                fileExt     = oldFileUri.split('.').pop();
              console.log("fileExt: "+fileExt);

                newFileName = "my_avatar" + "." + fileExt;
              console.log("newFileName: "+newFileName);
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory,
                        function(dirEntry) {
                            // move the file to a new directory and rename it
                            fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, newFileName, successCallback, errorCallback);
                        },
                        errorCallback);
          },
          errorCallback);
    }, function(e) {
      console.error('Error requesting file system: '+ e.code);
    });
}
function successCallback(entry) {
    console.log("entry: "+JSON.stringify(entry));
    console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
    console.log("native url: "+entry.nativeURL); // <<--- this is the new url: file:///data/data/com.intel.appx.RotarApp.xwalk15/files/my_avatar.jpg
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result seems to be the same. Only the success callbacks are triggered, but the path remains the same before and after copyTo. And it's not the same as cordova.file.dataDirectory.